# Moving a row in UITableView with many rows

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with thousands of rows. The following code makes the app slow to a crawl:

```
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath toIndexPath:toIndexPath];
```

Profiling tells me that the `UITableView` is calling both `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` for **alls rows**! Obviously, calculating the heights of thousands cells is too much of a strain for a simple move.

Is this the expected behavior? I don't understand why the `UITableView` needs the height of all cells to move two. **Is there something I can do to avoid this?**

I reproduced the problem with a vanilla `UITableView`: `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called for every row when moving two rows, no matter what.

(It should be noted that `fromIndexPath` and `toIndexPath` are consecutive index paths)

Comment: But if you have implemented `estimatedHeightForRow` and `heightForRow` correctly, those methods should return _instantly_ even if they are called for all rows. So the problem may lie in your implementation. I would suggest that you keep profiling at a finer grain of detail...

Comment: Just to modify my previous comment: You _may_ have stumbled on a bug involving Apple's implementation of when to call `estimatedHeightForRow` and `heightForRow` in relation to one another. I'm not denying that Apple could have messed up here! But one would need to know more about _your_ implementation of these methods before concluding that.

Comment: @matt I think I am. `estimatedHeightForRow` returns instantly. `heightForRow` uses a cache but the first time it does requite a few milliseconds per call. In any case, why the need to calculate the height for *all* cells?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the call to `moveRow...` with `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. That's not needed.

Comment: If you are showing a `UITableView` with more rows than you can count, you may have a UX problem on your hands.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, leftover from the original code. The slowdown happens anyway if I remove them so I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Pranav I'm profiling worst case scenarios. No need to use the UX card. :)

Comment: @matt If it's a bug, it's been there since iOS 6.0 at least. I reproduced the problem with a vanilla `UITableView`: `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called for every row when moving two rows, no matter what.

Comment: But @hpique hear what I'm saying. By the time you get around to moving rows, the values for `heightForRow` should all be memo-ized, so the "calculation" should be instant, as I said before. And thus it doesn't _matter_ that `heightForRow` is being called for every row. After all, the same thing happens on `reloadData`, and you don't complain about a speed bump there. That is why I suggest that maybe _you_ are doing something wrong. But you seem reluctant to show your code.

Comment: @matt The point of using `estimatedHeightForRow` is avoiding to calculate the heights of all cells, just only those who are visible. My reasoning is that moving two visible cells shouldn't require calculating the real height of all non-visible cells. Hope I explained myself now. Also, I'm not reluctant to show the code (here it is: https://github.com/hpique/HPReorderTableView). I simply don't think it's relevant as the same problem happens with a vanilla `UITableView`.

Comment: @hpique "The point of using estimatedHeightForRow is avoiding to calculate the heights of all cells" Agreed. That is why I said you _may_ have discovered an Apple bug. "the same problem happens with a vanilla UITableView" No, because (as you keep forcing me to repeat) if you've implemented `heightForRow` correctly, it _isn't_ a problem.

Comment: "here it is" Oh come on. Where do you want me to look? I can't find _any_ implementation of `heightForRow` here. And there is a lot more stuff going on in this example. Just boil it down to the simplest possible case and prove that there's a real issue _with a correct implementation_ of `heightForRow` (forget about `estimatedHeight` for now).

Comment: @matt Maybe I'm missing something? Take a `UITableView` with 100 cells. Implement `estimatedHeightForRow` and `heightForRow`. estimatedHeightForRow will be called 100 times and heightForRow only for the visible cells. Move the first two. `estimatedHeightForRow` will be called 100 times again and `heightForRow` for all cells, visible or not. That looks like a performance problem to me. What am I missing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47787/discussion-between-hpique-and-matt)